# How to wait for thread to wait

Tags: java, multithreading, join, wait

I want to wait until thread get's in to wait state. I been trying to use join(see below) but it did not work. How to achieve this?

```
public Test() {
    System.out.print("Started");
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (Test.class) {
            try {
                Test.class.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("Done");
}
```

Done is never printed.

Comment: That's because Test.class is never notified. What exactly are you trying to do? Wait for some async operation to finish? Then use Futures ...

Comment: You realise your thread isn't doing anything useful and isn't needed, so this doesn't demonstrate what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: I would suggest to look into countdown latches. I had a similar problem with a GUI and SwingWorkers previously. The way latches work are that you define how many you need (if you have 2 threads you need a single latch with input parameter 2). You pass the latch into the constructor of the thread and then when the thread finishes you do latch.countdown(). In the main part of your program you would do latch.wait(). Once the latch reaches 0 the program will continue. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main thread doesn't progress beyond `join()` because the second thread never ends. The second thread never ends because it's waiting for a notification on `Test.class` but nobody notifies it.

If you want your main thread to continue executing when the second thread reaches the `Test.class.wait();` line, you need to introduce another monitor for this synchronization. The main thread must wait on this monitor and the second thread must notify it when it's ready to switch to the waiting status:

```
System.out.println("Started");
final Object monitor = new Object();
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
    synchronized (monitor) {
        monitor.notify();  // Notify the main thread
    }
    synchronized (Test.class) {
        try {
            Test.class.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();

synchronized (monitor) {
    try {
        monitor.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

This code will work, though it looks a bit ugly. It also leaves a hanging thread that will prevent your program from terminating gracefully. You need someone to call `Test.class.notify()` if you want this thread to finish.

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve in general. If you want to spawn a thread and wait until it's finished, you don't need those `wait()`s and `notify()`s, just use `join()`:

```
System.out.println("Started");
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
});
thread.start();

try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

And one more thing: Creating and starting threads in a constructor is a very bad idea. Use a separate method (like `initialize()`) for that.

Comment: You got me in your first example, I just hoped there is some native alternative to that... But your suggestion looks good too! Tnx.